# DIfference between output of sublime 3 vs jupyter

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I have a problem with the output of sublime text. When I run this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['John', 'Steve', 'Sarah']
df.assign (age =[30,31,32])
print (df)
```

I get this result:

```
        name
    0   John
    1  Steve
    2  Sarah
```

I think this is a mistake, because I should can see the age column.

When I Run this code in jupyter I obtain:

```
    name    age
0   John    30
1   Steve   31
2   Sarah   32
```

Somebody have any idea what it happen?

thanks for the help

Comment: No, it is NOT a mistake. `df.assign(age =[30,31,32])` is ***NOT done in place***. So `df` still only has one column. The reason you see it in `jupyter` is because `jupyter` actually has a `REPL` feature. Sublime does not. It would work in both if you did: `df = df.assign(age =[30,31,32])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This is far from being a mistake or an interpreter mismatch*.

When you call `df.assign(age =[30,31,32])`, you are making a copy of `df` with an additional column `age`. When this is done in a `REPL-like` editor, you see the ouput rendered. But in most text editors, this will not show because you are not printing the ouput. You are using the `__repr__` method of the `DataFrame` object. Unless the text editor has implemented a way to render `__repr__` ouputs, you will never see the output of `df.assign(age =[30,31,32])`.

Now, `jupyter`, on the other hand, has a `REPL` feature, and therefore will show commands based on the output's `__repr__` method, without needing to call the `print` function. As a result, `jupyter` will show the output of `df.assign(age =[30,31,32])`.

The bottom line remains that you are not changing the dataframe in place. Both sublime and `jupyter` would print the results, if the code was written as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = ['John', 'Steve', 'Sarah']
df = df.assign(age=[30,31,32])
print(df)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `assign()` of dataframe *returns* a new object (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones - see [pandas.DataFrame.assign](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html).

So you have to assign it for getting its return value:

```
df = df.assign (age =[30,31,32])
```